# Displaying data from Sql DB in MVC using EF

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a little problem in displaying data in MVC  and the error is

> EntityType 'Employee' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   Employees: EntityType: EntitySet 'Employees' is based on type 'Employee' that has no keys defined.

Here are my models

**Employee** (model)

```
namespace MVCFirstApp.Models{
[Table("TblEmployee")]
public class Employee
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int Mobile { get; set; }
}
```

**EmployeeDb** (model)

```
namespace MVCFirstApp.Models{
public class EmployeeDb:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { set; get; }
}
```

**Home** (controller)

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult EMployeeDetails()
    {
        EmployeeDb EmpDbObj = new EmployeeDb();
        var EmpObj = EmpDbObj.Employees.ToList();
        return View(EmpObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: EF will automatically use a column called `Id` or `(tablename)Id` (in your case: `EmployeeId`) as the primary key. If you don't have any of those columns (which is the case here), you **must** decorate the appropriate column with a `[Key]` attribute instead

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `[Key]` before your PRIMARY KEY. In your case:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int Mobile { get; set; }
}
```